# Relax rng xml schema - tools for C# code generation

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, code-generation, relaxng

Are there any tool for generating C# cs files from Relax schema definition files (*.rng)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to generate XML Schema from rng.